# How to get frame number of Blackdetect result?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, h.264

I am attempting to get the frame number of a black detect result. For instance, on Blackdetect I get two results that display a start time, end time and duration, how do I get the frame number of the start time?

`FPS is 59.94`

Here's my command I'm working with to get my blackdetect:

```
ffmpeg –i e1.mp4 –vf “blackdetect=d=0:pix_th=0.40,” –an –f null -
```

It results in (the start time value is the frame's timestamp (ffmpeg wiki says))

```
[blackdetect @ 000001f4d022c900] black_start:1.06773 black_end:1.08442 black_duration:0.0166833
[blackdetect @ 000001f4d022c900] black_start:1.41808 black_end:1.43477 black_duration:0.0166833
```

When I append `-n` to it to hopefully display the frame number however, it spits out 3 entries of random frame numbers that aren't even remotely close to the blackdetect frame number really is

```
ffmpeg –i e1.mov –vf “blackdetect=d=0:pix_th=0.40” -n –an –f null - 2>showinfo.log
```

How can I get the frame number of the start time of blackdetect?

Comment: You need to share actual numbers for the video's FPS and also the start time, then we can try to answer you... Anyways the formula needs an **FPS** and also your **start time** in milliseconds (or as: `seconds * 1000`). Calculate as: `(1000 / FPS) * startTime == frame num`.

Comment: I updated the ask with the additonal info. I understand the formula to retrieve the frame number but am unsure how I will incorporate that to my command to use the info of the blackdetect to retrive that frame number

Comment: I am not on FFmpeg right now, so try this Answer: https://superuser.com/a/1707803. PS: Try the bottom option first (where it's using timestamp directly) or else go the first shown method (using frame numbers).

Answer (score 0):

Try the `blackframe` filter instead.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf blackframe -an -f null -
```

Detect frames that are (almost) completely black.

It accepts the following parameters:

`amount`
The percentage of the pixels that have to be below the threshold; it defaults to 98.

`threshold`, `thresh`
The threshold below which a pixel value is considered black; it defaults to 32.